# is there an inside-Eclipse continuous-integration tool for javascript that looks like infinitest?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, testing, infinitest

When I program in Java, I have recently discovered the free unit-testing tool Infinitest, and installed it as an Eclipse Plugin. The GUI is minimalistic and looks like this statusbar at bottom of picture:

[image: screenshot infinitest]

(The bar is green when all tests pass, and it is red if tests fail.)

Is there a similar tool that inserts a status bar into Eclipse like this, but works for unit tests written **in Javascript**?

I would also be interested in solutions that work for any other language but can be adapted for javascript. And the test runner does not necessarily have to be an eclipse plugin. I'm interested in having seamless workflow with instant feedback from the test runner (just as in Infinitest). Whenever I save a script file, the  testrunner gets triggered.